# Math differences in Swift and Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am trying to figure out the differences in Math (there shouldn't be any) between a quick calculation in Swift and Objective-C:

**Swift**

```
let z1 = 1.0
let width = 0.02197265625
let extent = 4096.0
let dx = z1 * width / extent
print(dx)

// 5.364418029785156e-06
```

**Objective-C**

```
double z1 = 1.0;
double width = 0.02197265625;
double extent = 4096.0;
double dx = z1 * width / extent;
NSLog(@"%f", dx);

// 0.000005
```

Inputting the numbers into a calculator return what `Objective-C` provides.

**What is Swift doing differently here?**

Comment: `print` is not the same as `NSLog` with a format string

Comment: AFAIK, they both strictly follow IEEE754, so you shouldn't see any differences in the actual values. As far as _presentation_ goes though, all bets are off. `print` and `NSLog` clearly differ, and there's no real reason to expect them to behave identically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both languages return the same number but they are formatted differently. I assume that you understand the scientific notation 5.36e-06 is the same as 0.00000536.

The format specifiers of `NSLog` follow the [IEEE printf specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html). When describing the specifier `f`, it says:

> If the precision is missing, it shall be taken as 6;

So it's rounded to 6 digits after the  point, without using scientific notation (like *e-06*). It means that all except a single digits are removed.

Swift's `print` function doesn't use format specifiers. Instead, the documentation state:

> The textual representation for each item is the same as that obtained by calling `String(item)`.

It obviously choses to print it with scientific notation and the maximum number of relevant digits.